# WPF good practice about open window and back button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm beginner programmer in WPF MVVM C#. When user install my app he will follow a tutorial. So, for each "screen" of tutorial I created a Window.
On each screen, I have a Back Button.

So, I'm really confused on the good practice about open new window and back to the previous Window. What is the best way to do this? Currently, I'm doing:

**First Window (Next Step Button) - ViewModel1**

```
<Button Command="{Binding NextWindowCommand}" >


public void NextWindow(object parameter)
{
    var newWindow = new Window2();
    newWindow.Show();
    newWindow.DataContext = new ViewModel2();
    CloseWindow();
}
```

**Second Window (Back Button) ViewModel2**

```
<Button Command="{Binding BackWindowCommand}" >

    public void Back(object parameter)
    {
        var backWindow = new Window1();
        backWindow.Show();
        backWindow.DataContext = new ViewModel1();
        CloseWindow();
    }
```

**Close Window Method (My ViewModelBase):**

```
    public bool? CloseWindowFlag
    {
        get { return _CloseWindowFlag; }
        set
        {
            _CloseWindowFlag = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CloseWindowFlag");
        }
    }


public virtual void CloseWindow(bool? result = true)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
    {
        CloseWindowFlag = CloseWindowFlag == null 
            ? true 
            : !CloseWindowFlag;
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is appropriate to use `DataTemplates` if you want to dynamically switch Views depending on the `ViewModel`:

```
<Window>
   <Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelA}">
         <localControls:ViewAUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelB}">
         <localControls:ViewBUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
   <Window.Resources>
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
</Window>
```

If `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModelA`, then `ViewA` will be displayed and `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModelB`, then `ViewB` will be displayed.

The best example I've ever seen and read it is made by Rachel Lim. [See the example.](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

And I highly recommend you pay attention to `Prism` framework. [This tutorial is very nice.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165370/Creating-View-Switching-Applications-with-Prism)

**Update:**

Let me show an example where it can be seen where you should put `DataTemplates`:

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleMVVMExample.ApplicationView"
        ...The code omitted for the brevity...
        Title="Simple MVVM Example with Navigation" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelA}">
         <localControls:ViewAUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelB}">
         <localControls:ViewBUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfViewModels}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                                Margin="2,5"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Border>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentDataTemplateViewModel}" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

To see full work example, [please, see Rachel Lim's page.](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

To download the example, [please, click here.](http://www.mediafire.com/download/21g3er1ant6m99a/SimpleMVVMExampleWithNavigation.zip)

Comment: hey @StepUp thanks for you answer. But where I add this DataTemplate, on with XAML?

Comment: @Lücks I've updated my answer. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: @Lücks feel free to ask any question. If you feel that my reply helps to you, you can mark my reply as an answer. It will simplify the future search of other people.

Comment: I chose to work with Caliburn.Micro, but your answer it's really good alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all It would be nice to know what you have inside your windows for the tutorial, is it just text or also controls to be filled? like textbox, checkbox and other things.
Said so, if you want to avoid creating new windows every time your user hits the next or previous button I suggest you to create the windows once and then create a collection List adding the windows to the collection and using then the Visibility to hide the windows when the user presses the next or previous button. You can use the collection index to navigate the windows in the collection and a selected window property to get the right window and set it visible or bring it to front.

Answer (score 1):

Good practices for your project:

1. Use a framework to manage your windows (like Caliburn.Micro or MVVM Light),
2. Use DI to crate view models,
3. One of goodies of MVVM is that the 'back' operation is almost for free. Just when the user leaves one window to go to the new one, remember the old view model on the stack. When he clicks 'back' - just close the current window, pop the view model from the stack, and display it.